# auto memory management for RedisModule_Alloc() in Redis

Tags: c, module, redis

Inside a Redis module, we can let the Redis manages memory automatically.
Redis document says this

> When automatic memory management is enabled:
>
> 1. You don't need to close open keys.
> 2. You don't need to free replies.
> 3. You don't need to free RedisModuleString objects.

Apart from these, Does Redis free the memory allocated using RedisModule_Alloc() also? Or Does the developer have to free them manually?

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocated by `RedisModule_Alloc()`, `RedisModule_Calloc()` and `RedisModule_Realloc()` needs to be explicitly freed by the module via a call to `RedisModule_Free()`.

For reference, look at the native type's example callback for freeing the type - https://redis.io/topics/modules-native-types#free-method